# How to disable bash argument splitting?

Tags: bash, shell

I want to input any line to my script, and treat it "as is", like a single argument, no splitting by spaces or anything, not removing double spaces.
Example:

```
# op.sh
IFS=$'\n'
echo "$*"

./op.sh one two   three
one
two
three

# Desired output
./op.sh one two   three
one two   three
```

So it reads until newline (enter).

Comment: If you could do that, how would the shell know where the command name stops and the arguments begin? Quoting is your friend: `./op.sh 'one two   three'`

Comment: @glennjackman edited

Comment: @roaima edited question

Comment: Splitting is all done in the *calling* shell prior to calling execve, not in your script, so you need to change `$IFS` there, not in op.sh.

Comment: @ChrisDown how do I do that?

Comment: If you want an argument to a program to have spaces in it, then quote the argument.  You'll need to do this whether you want the space(s) at the start, somewhere the middle, and/or the end of the argument.   Quotes are how you tell the shell: `this is one "word", even if it has spaces in it, so don't split it`.  You're trying to come up with your own weird, non-standard "solution" to a problem that has had a standard, well-known solution for decades, since the 1960s or 1970s at least.   Probably since the first programming language needed strings.

Comment: Trivia: in \*nix an executable gets an array of arguments. It's the shell who splits a string to an array. In Windows an executable gets a single string and has to do the splitting on its own. It can use a standard function for this or provide its own function instead to do anything with the string. A script like `op.sh` has no means to do this, but binary `op.exe` can disable splitting this way. When called from `cmd.exe`, `op.exe one two   three` can behave like you want. But when called from Bash in Windows it cannot really, because Bash does the splitting regardless of what happens next.

Answer (score 2):

A program (script, application, whatever) does not get to see the command line that invoked it. It gets given a series of zero of more parameters parsed by the invoking shell.

For example, when you run `ls f*` it's not `ls` that handles the `f*`, it's the shell. If you had three files beginning with f, then `ls f*` might be parsed by the shell to become `ls final food fred`, and it's this that is executed. In this situation `ls` sees these three arguments and not the `f*`

Similarly, when you execute `./op.sh one two   three` the shell parses this as `./op.sh` and three space-separated arguments, `one`, `two`, and `three`. The whitespace is thrown away as part of the parsing. You can see this with a script like this

```
#!/bin/bash
for a in $*; do echo "Found * argument ($a)"; done
echo
for a in "$@"; do echo "Found @ argument ($a)"; done
echo
echo "All together, they are ($*)"
```

If it's called `args` you could make it executable (`chmod a+x args`) and then invoke it like this

```
./args one two   three
```

The corresponding output is

```
Found * argument (one)
Found * argument (two)
Found * argument (three)

Found @ argument (one)
Found @ argument (two)
Found @ argument (three)

All together, they are (one two three)
```

If you experiment with this you may notice that `$*` represents the command line arguments each separated with a single space, but also with internal spaces split out once more. *This is not generally useful*. Instead use double-quoted `"$@"`, which further protects against inadvertent parsing of the arguments. Either way, though, the arguments are reconstructed from the parsed arguments and are not a copy of the original command line.

To keep whitespace intact you must quote the string. Double quotes allows variables and `$(...)` constructs to be expanded. Single quotes leaves you with a literal. Here I'm using single quotes

Quoted whitespace

```
./args 'one two   three'
Found * argument (one)
Found * argument (two)
Found * argument (three)

Found @ argument (one two   three)

All together, they are (one two   three)
```

Single quotes

```
'one more $HOME to go'
Found * argument (one)
Found * argument (more)
Found * argument ($HOME)
Found * argument (to)
Found * argument (go)

Found @ argument (one more $HOME to go)

All together, they are (one more $HOME to go)
```

Double quotes

```
./args "one more $HOME to go"
Found * argument (one)
Found * argument (more)
Found * argument (/home/roaima)
Found * argument (to)
Found * argument (go)

Found @ argument (one more /home/roaima to go)

All together, they are (one more /home/roaima to go)
```

Comment: Thanks very informative. What happens if I use another shell like ksh, fish, etc.? Or if I use another terminal emulator?

Comment: A terminal emulator is your interface to the shell. I'm not familiar with `fish` but I would expect the behaviour of all shells to be the same as far as parsing unquoted words goes, i.e. you need to write a string to retain whitespace

Answer (score 2):

This type of splitting has nothing to do with IFS.

It is the very basic kind of splitting that converts a line into words.

Words are the individual tokens over which a shell could act. Like reading a sentence is done by dividing it into words first and then understanding what the words mean.

The only way to avoid such splitting is by quoting. That is the fundamental reason why quoting got invented.

```
$ op.sh () { printf '%s\n' "$@"; }

$ op.sh one two three
one
two
three

$ op.sh "one two three"
one two three
```

There is no more magic to it.